# How to customize doctrine results?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I've seen some post with something that looks like my problem but I must be too much of a beginner to understand.
I got a database that looks like this :

[image: Database table]

in my symfony controller (named `QuizController`) I do this:

```
$quiz = $em->getRepository(Quiz::class)
    ->findAll()
```

I've heard of doctrine `QueryBuilder` but don't know how to use it, I need to do 2 things :

1. I got to find a way to do some kind of `SELECT and GROUP BY` to have only entries that are from "Héros Marvel" "theme" and that is from "difficulty" "3".
2. When I select the question with id "1" for example, how can I get answer_a, answer_b, answer_c and answer_d into an array so I can do something like `$randomAnswer = shuffle($myAnswersArray)` ?

Comment: I'd recommend looking into the basics of [database design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). If you get the table into first normal form (that's modelled using [relations](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional) in doctrine) it's trivial to get an array using [`Collection`](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-collections/en/1.6/index.html#toarray) methods. You can also add more answers per question or a way to mark the correct answer much easier.

Comment: Please open a seperate question for each of your questions. Additionally, provide your attempts

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can use `findBy()` function instead of `findAll()`

```
$all_quiz = $em->getRepository(Quiz::class)->findBy(
[ 'theme' => 'Héros Marvel' ,
'difficulty' => 3 ]);
```

Since the number of questions is fixed to 4,
then you can store the questions in a table and then `shuffle()` the table:

```
foreach ($all_quiz as $quiz) {
    $answers =[$quiz->getAnswerA(), $quiz->getAnswerB() , $quiz->getAnswerC() , $quiz->getAnswerD()];
    shuffle($answers);
    $randomAnswers=$answers;
}
```